# JSF datatable with more than 30 columns

Tags: jsf

I've a problem with jsf datatable. i need to display 30 columns in the table in which first 15 is in one line and next 15 are in the next line and both should be in one row only.i am trying to wrap the columns is there any css attributes or any property in jsf datatable itself.

THANKS for the responces.

Comment: Show what you have done so far, and an example of what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the content of the 1st and 16th column, 2nd and 17th column, 3rd and 18th column, etcetera in the same `<h:column>`, separated by a `<br/>`, `<hr/>` or maybe even inside a `<h:panelGrid>`.

E.g.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    <h:column>#{item.col1}<br/>#{item.col16}</h:column>
    <h:column>#{item.col2}<br/>#{item.col17}</h:column>
    <h:column>#{item.col3}<br/>#{item.col18}</h:column>
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Note that you may want to use `<h:outputText>` to be able to use a converter which can convert spaces to non-breakable spaces.

Comment: @Thor: or, easier, apply CSS `white-space: nowrap` on the `<td>`.

Comment: dear Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen thank you very much for your answer